# Slider not work perfectly - 2 images is displayed in slider

Tags: jquery

[This is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lucdkny/38fvj8uL/)

```
<div id="index-1" class="main-wrapper">
<div id="bg" class="main">
    <img alt="Main BG" src="http://dedicatedguru.com/demo/mhsplanner/wp-content/uploads/wedding-plan.jpg" class="main-bg" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
    <img alt="Brand BG" src="http://dedicatedguru.com/demo/mhsplanner/wp-content/uploads/event-plan.jpg" class="brand-bg" style="display: none; width: 100%;">
    <img style="display: none; width: 100%;" alt="INspiration" src="http://dedicatedguru.com/demo/mhsplanner/wp-content/uploads/wedding-consultant.jpg" class="inspiration-bg">
</div>
<section id="our-services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="services-col">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-4" id="main-bg">
                <a href="/#">
                    <div class="service2 service-2" data-img="main-bg">
                        <div class="service-details2" align="center">
                            <h3>Wedding Planning Services</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-4">
                <a href="/#">
                    <div class="service2 service-2" data-img="brand-bg">
                        <div class="service-details2" align="center">
                            <h3>Event Planning Services</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-4" id="inspiration-bg">
                <a href="/#">
                    <div class="service2 service-2" data-img="inspiration-bg">
                        <div class="service-details2" align="center">
                            <h3>Wedding Consultant Services</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</section>
<!-- /#our-services -->
```

```
$(function(){
        $(".service2").hover(function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            $('#bg').children('img').each(function () {
              $(this).css("display", "none");
            });
            $('.'+$(this).data("img")).css("display", "block");
        });
    });
    $('#bg').hover(function(ev){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }, function(ev){
        timer = setInterval(function() { 
              $('#bg > img:first')
                .css("display", "none")
                .next()
                .css("display", "block")
                .end()
                .appendTo('#bg');
            },  3000);
    })
```

I have create a simple slider by js. But I have a problem, as my demo above. - Slider will change when I hover 3 block inside it.
- When not hover, it will change automatically
-> My problems is when I hover in third block (and then hover out) for example, but the "Interval" function will display the image number 2 automatically after that. Then my slider broken (Image number 2 and 3 will display both).
Could you help me solve this problem. Many thanks!

Comment: I'm using Chrome Win8 and it works. If I hover over the flowers (on the right), then slide 1 (yellow banquet hall on left) is next.

Comment: so once hovered out you want to show image from beginning?

Comment: Okay, my problems is solved as @Guruprasad Rao demo bellow. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/38fvj8uL/3/)**

2 problems:

> - **First** - *You haven't declared variable timer and it was giving console error*
> - **Second** - *You were not hiding all images before going to the next round after hover out*

So below are the changes you need to do:

```
var timer; //problem one - A global variable timer
$(function(){
        $(".service2").hover(function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            $('#bg').children('img').each(function () {
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            });
            $('.'+$(this).data("img")).css("display", "block");
        });
});
$('#bg').hover(function(ev){
    clearInterval(timer);
    }, function(ev){
    timer = setInterval(function() { 
         $("#bg img").css('display','none'); //hide all the images before starting up again
         $('#bg > img:first').next()
         .css("display", "block")
         .end()
         .appendTo('#bg');
    },  3000);
})
```